# PHP Mongo Library overflow detected

Tags: php, mongodb

i've a problem with the MongoDB PHP library. I'am trying to find something in a collection but get this error.

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Integer overflow detected on your platform: 1484960424767 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php:222 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php(222): MongoDB\Driver\Cursor->setTypeMap(Array) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\FindOne.php(105): MongoDB\Operation\Find->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Collection.php(559): MongoDB\Operation\FindOne->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\index.php(7): MongoDB\Collection->findOne(Array) 
#4 {main} Next MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Integer overflow detected on your platform: 1484960529934 in C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php:222 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php(222): MongoDB\Driver\Cursor->setTypeMap(Array) 
#1 C:\ in C:\xampp\htdocs\gameid\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php on line 222
```

Here is my source code:

```
$con = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://user:pwd@ip:port/ripes');
$con = $con->ripes->games;

$result = $con->findOne(['gameID' => 'KUDl-xvjWkPJkjTRf-']);
```

What is wrong? If no entry exists with the id, PHP does not report any errors.

Comment: Do you have a massive amount of items in your DB instance?

Comment: In the DB is only one item

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same *Integer overflow* PHP exception.  Take a look at your error message again, it is telling you exactly what caused the exception:

```
Integer overflow detected on your platform: 1484960424767
```

I was able to use Robo3T (RoboMongo) to view the document in question and see the field with the value that caused the exception (1484960424767 in your case).  In the MongoDB document, the field was defined as type NumberLong(), and the value exceeds PHP's capability to parse long integers on the version you're using... most likely 32-bit PHP.  Try using 64-bit PHP, if possible.

In my case, the document field was supposed to be a string, so I had to modify the document-creation script to force the value to be a string type.

```
$doc = array(
             "field" => (string)$long_number_value
            );
```